# Magento update subtotal item

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I can't update subtotal item in cart.
I created module with observe **checkout_cart_product_add_after** I can get subtotal price from item:

```
$subtotal = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
```

but I can't update this, for exmaple:

```
$subtotal = $subtotal + 100;
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setSubtotal($subtotal);
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setSubtotal($subtotal);
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->save();
```

**EDIT**

If I run in my Observer `print_r($subtotal); exit;` 
I get correct updated subtotal. In cart page I have still orginal subtotal without change.

**EDIT 2**
I'm trying run modifySubtotal function with **sales_quote_collect_totals_after** event, but I can't see on cart page updated subtotal price. Below code of modifySubtotal from Observer.php:

```
public function modifySubtotal(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $quote=$observer->getQuote();
    $subtotal = $quote->getBaseSubtotal();
    $subtotal = $subtotal +123;
    $quote->setBaseSubtotal($subtotal);

    $quote->save();
    $subtotal2 = $quote->getBaseSubtotal();
    //print_r($subtotal2);exit;

}
```

I'll be grateful for any tips and help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue solved. I override and copy **Subtotal.php** from **Tax/Module/Sales/Qoute/Total** to /app/local/Mage/... Near 545 line I calculated my custom `$subtotal` value and set `$item->setRowTotal($subtotal);`This is all.

Comment: I guess you could used an observer or a rewrite class for doing that. Doing this way, you will loose compatibility to future versions and could have some imprevisible problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should observe `sales_quote_collect_totals_after`.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, but in my case I still can't see updated subtotal in cart.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is here:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote=$observer->getQuote();
```

This needs to be

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote=$session->getQuote();
```

Hope this helps