# Magento Update Subtotal

Tags: php, magento

I've tried the suggestions here: [Magento update subtotal item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347262/magento-update-subtotal-item)

I have a Magento site with several extensions.  We're using Amasty to add 'bonus' items.  The problem is we want those items to show up and be added to the subtotal if the user selects 30 day billing.

I've tried making a simple extension and hooking to various events, but it looks like Amasty always has the last word when updating the subtotal.

I've even modified the Dispatcher so that it logs who it's dispatching to to see if I can track down where it's getting updated but to no avail.

How can I make sure that the extension I write is the final one to update the subtotal/total for the order?

It's right after checkout that it's being updated by something to exclude the bonus item.s

Answer (score 0):

Checkout sort order for each order total module.

On times one of the order total modules sort order is higher then total module.

Or logically sort orders have some wrong values.

First you need to check that.

I had seen something similar happen when an old Magento commerce version was updated.

Comment: Is there a place in the backend that shows the sort order?  I don't see a way to edit that in the xml file.  Oddly enough, it looks like the amasty plugin isn't being detected in my debugging script that show's what the dispatcher is dispatching and to whom.

Comment: <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <customerbalance>
                        <class>enterprise_customerbalance/total_quote_customerbalance</class>
                        <after>weee,discount,tax,tax_subtotal,grand_total,reward,giftcardaccount</after>
                        <renderer>enterprise_customerbalance/checkout_total</renderer>
                    </customerbalance>
                </totals>
            </quote>  Something like this is what you will find in xml